# Find the next table after h3 tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is what I am working with:

```
<table class="info-table"></table>
<h3><span id="regular_text">Regular Text</span></h3>
<table class="info-table"></table> <!--Give this table an id.-->
```

I need to give the 2nd table an id but I'm not sure how I can reach it. Is there some sort of jQuery or JavaScript that can compute the "next" table after `h3 #regular_text`?

Comment: What are you trying to do to this table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

```
document.querySelector('h3 + table');
```

If you need to select the table that's immediately after the `h3` tag that contains an element with the id `regular_text`, I'm not aware of a pure CSS selector solution, but you can do it in plain JS like this:

```
var heading = document.getElementById('regular_text').parentElement;
var table = heading.nextElementSibling;
table.id = 'tableId';
```

Comment: This is mostly good, but the description sounds like they need to take into account the `#regular_text` as well, which can't currently be done in native selectors.